# AWS cognito global sign out token regular expression error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using aws cognito, but not doing anything to close the connection after sign out. So I am trying to use aws cognito global sign out to invalid the cogntio token that I received while sign in.

But this is giving me error saying "**Error performing global sign-out: InvalidParameterException: 1 validation error detected: Value at 'accessToken' failed to satisfy coonstraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [A-Za-z0-9-_=.]+**"

The problem seems to be the cognito token contains "/" while this is not allowed in global sign out parameter.

Here is my node code

```
async function globalSignOut(req, res) {
try {
  let {accessToken} =  req.body;

  const cognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
    const params = {
      AccessToken: accessToken
    };
    const data = await cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.globalSignOut(params).promise();
    console.log('Successfully performed global sign-out:', data);
    res.status(200).json('Successfully performed global sign-out');
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error performing global sign-out:', error);
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: 'Error performing global sign-out' });
}
```

}

I am passing the exact token I received from cognito, so do not understand how this format could be wrong.